Conversion of integral to summation of q points?
I have a question regarding the conversion of integral to summation (considering 1st Brillouin Zone) of q points. In the equations (5 to 9) of the following journal, they have shown the conversion of integral to summation of q points.
https://journals.aps.org/prapplied/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.14.024080


They mentioned that A (Area) is the area of sample. However, when I considered the Area as unit cell area (instead area of sample), I have seen reasonable data.
For example:
$s=\int{f(q)\frac{d^2q}{{(2\pi)}^2}}$
Replacing the integral of this Eq. by a sum of parallel wave vectors in the first Brillouin zone, we get
$s=\frac{1}{A}\sum_{q\in1BZ}{f(q)}$
What is Area (A) here? Is it area of primitive unit cell?
or the area of the sample (=number of q points* unit cell area)?
Would you please explain me?
Thank you.
